# Unable to read resource as stream

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x

I am trying to read an HTML file from disk. But it always returns null. I have tried putting the everywhere in the directory but still, it returns null.

```
class MainVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {

  override fun start(startPromise: Promise<Void>) {
    vertx
      .createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler { req ->
       req.response()
      .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
      .end("Hello from Vert.x!")
     }
     .listen(8888) { http ->
        if (http.succeeded()) {
          startPromise.complete()
          println("HTTP server started on port 8888")
        } else {
          startPromise.fail(http.cause());
        }
      }

    var mailTemplateStream = (getStreamFromRes("emailVerification.html") as 
    InputStream).reader().readText()
    println(mailTemplateStream)

  }

  fun getStreamFromRes(fileName: String): InputStream? {
  val stream = Object::class.java.getResourceAsStream("/$fileName")
  return stream
 }
}
```

It always throws the following exception :-

```
SEVERE: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.io.InputStream
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type 
java.io.InputStream
    at example.starter.MainVerticle.start(MainVerticle.kt:26)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$9(DeploymentManager.java:556)
    at 
   io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:369)
at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here through function getStreamFromRes, I am trying to get the input stream. I have placed the file emailVerification.html just beside the MainVerticle class but still, it returns null. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Update:-
I have added this project on my github project:- 
https://github.com/captabhi/abhishek09021998-gmail.com.git

Comment: `Object::class.java.getResourceAsStream` will try to find the resource in the JDK. I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: No, I want to read a file that is in the same directory as the class MainVerticle.

Comment: Then use `MainVerticle`, not `Object`.

Comment: I just tried that also, but it still doesn't work. I have added a Github link to this project in case you want to test it yourself.

Comment: try to run mvn clean verify if using maven

Answer (score 0):

your emailVerification.html file should be copied into the build folder, along with the compiled class files. every source files resides in the resources folder does not mean it will be automatically picked up by the classloader. your build script should copied the resources into the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your GitHub project is a bit different from the examples code you supplied. I've cloned your project and basing my answer on it, and not on the code in the question.

Correct implementation of `getStreamFromRes` should be:

```
fun getStreamFromRes(fileName: String) = this::class.java.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

Note that there's no backslash before `fileName`, and so we also don't have to interpolate it.

In your code, you can also avoid casts using

```
val mailTemplateStream = getStreamFromRes("mail/emailVerification.html")?.reader()?.readText()
```